# Problem linking the c graphics library with the Windows API

Tags: linker, linker-errors

I programmed in assembly using NASM and want to link it with the c graphics library.
My assembly code is good and I know, because I was able to link it using MinGW that came with Dev-cpp, but I can't link it using MinGW that I downloaded.
The command that I use is:

```
g++ -mwindows "test.obj" "libbgi.a"
```

where test.obj is my assembled assembly code and libbgi.a is the graphics library.
The error I get is:

```
libbgi.a(drawing.o):drawing.cxx:(.text+0x28b): undefined reference to `CreateStreamOnHGlobal@12'
libbgi.a(drawing.o):drawing.cxx:(.text+0x2a8): undefined reference to `IID_IPicture'
libbgi.a(drawing.o):drawing.cxx:(.text+0x2c2): undefined reference to `OleLoadPicture@20'
```

I tried downloading ole32.lib and link with it, but it only fixed the first one and left the other two.

Edit: 
My assembly code:

```
    extern _initwindow
    extern _getch
    extern _line
    global _main
    section .text
_main:
   push dword 600
   push dword 600
   call _initwindow
   add esp, 8
   push dword 100
   push dword 100
   push dword 500
   push dword 500
   call _line
   add esp, 16
   call _getch
   ret
```

And I compile with:

```
nasm -fwin32 test.asm
```

Answer (score 0):

[OleLoadPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/win32/api/olectl/nf-olectl-oleloadpicture) is defined in oleaut32.dll so you need to link `oleaut32.lib`.

To access `IID_IPicture` you need to link `uuid.lib`

Comment: This fixes the linkin proccess, but when I run the app, it doesn't do anything. The weird thing is that when I use MinGW from Dev-cpp, it doesn't even have any of those -lib files in it. If only I could figure out how it does things, I could do them too, but unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: @Joza100 maybe you forgot to initialize COM/OLE, it is better to show your code

Comment: I thought my code is okay, because it worked with older MinGW, but who knows, maybe my code really needs to change with newer versions of MinGW. I edited it and put my code into the question. I don't know how to initialize COM/OLE.